# Passing data between view models in MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently trying to create a "log" text box that gets messages between multiple view models (tied to multiple views) that I have.  I've tried the approach described by user Blachshma here ([Multiple Data Contexts in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282235/multiple-data-contexts-in-view)) but it does not seem to be working.

I have three classes.  Class AViewModel, Class BViewModel and Class ABViewModel.

The view for A binds to AViewModel using the following code in its constructor:

```
this.InitializeComponent();
this.model = new AViewModel();
this.DataContext = this.model;
```

The view for B and AB follows the same pattern.

The class structures are as follows:

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string log = string.empty;

    public class A()
    {
    }

    public string ALog
    {
        get
        {
            return this.log;
        }

        set
        {
            this.log = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ALog");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    /* Function that executes when relay command is clicked */
    private void ExecuteCommand()
    {
       this.ALog += "here";
    }
}
```

Class B is defined the same way with property BLog

Class ABViewModel has properties for each other view model

```
public class ABViewModel
{
    public AViewModel AVM
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public BViewModel BVM
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In the xaml I simply have 
`<TextBox Text="{Binding ABViewModel.AVM}" />`

My plan is to eventually using Multibinding to concatenate both logs together, but at the moment I can't even get the one View Model to update my string. It looks like my container view model ABViewModel isn't getting updated, but I don't really understand why, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

Any suggestions are extremely appreciated!

Thanks!

Edit:
I debug my code and see that my string ALog is getting updated, but I don't see the change on the UI.  For more information, I click a button that's connected to a RelayCommand in class A.  This button invokes a method to connect to a COM port.  I'm able to use the COM port from other view models successfully after opening it.  The log is supposed to update saying that the com port was opened but I never see any text added to the log in the GUI even though the instance of ALog that I can debug through has the added text.

I can't use Prism or MVVM-light for this particular project.

Comment: "I know it's because the ABViewModel (my container view model) isn't getting notified that it has changed". Oh yeah? That's what you think.

Comment: "it does not seem to be working."  Do you think you could provide just a little more detail about what you're doing to the ui, and what happens in response?

Comment: Hi Ed. I click a button on the UI that is mapped to a relay command inside class A.  The button merely connects to a serial port and then updates the log with a message that it has connected. I attempted to simplify it when I wrote out my code.  I can tell that I've connected to the COM port because I'm able to use other buttons on the UI to talk over that COM port.

Comment: I have to agree with some of @EdPlunkett's comments, however, if it helps somewhat; I would look into using PubSub events between ViewModels, so that they're not so tightly coupled. This allows for change and scaleability (if you have different/extra ViewModels relying on one event). I recommend looking into Prism's EventAggregator (other lib's are available). Have a look at this sample to get started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample